# Error performing request: in cloud foundry CLI

Tags: command-line-interface, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I have tried login through `cf cli` using the below command:

> C:\Users\sc00359878>cf l
>
> API endpoint> http://api.au-syd.bluemix.net

Even I have tried using `https://api.au-syd.bluemix.net` but I'm getting the below error:

> [image]

Comment: Hello Sharath, Please run the following commands and then execute cf login cf -v set CF_TRACE=true set CF_TRACE=<PathToLogFile>\cftrace.txt cf l -a https://api.au-syd.bluemix.net and paste the output from cftrace.txt file so that we can determine why you are unable to login. Kailash

Comment: below is the output from cftrace.txt,

` REQUEST: [2015-12-15T14:51:19+05:30] 
GET /v2/info HTTP/1.1
Host: api.au-syd.bluemix.net
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: go-cli 6.14.0+2654a47 / windows



REQUEST: [2015-12-15T14:51:34+05:30]
GET /v2/info HTTP/1.1
Host: api.au-syd.bluemix.net
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: go-cli 6.14.0+2654a47 / windows


FAILED
Error performing request: Get http://api.au-syd.bluemix.net/v2/info: dial tcp 168.1.35.169:80: i/o timeout `  @KailashPeri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case it was proxy issue. I have set some proxy command by using below command.

```
set http_proxy=8787
```

But then i have just applied below command to remove the proxy and it works for me.

```
set http_proxy=
```

For https you can use below command

```
set https_proxy=
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems a proxy/firewall issue. I suggest you to check that you are not blocked by some kind of proxy/firewall. If this is the case try to add the HTTP_PROXY environment variable for cf commands to get past the firewall. Take a look at the [Cloud Foundry Docs - Proxy](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/installcf/http-proxy.html).

Moreover, check if you have installed the [latest cf version](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli). I've just tried and it works for me with no proxy.

Comment: Hi i have added HTTP_PROXY environment variable. and installed the latest cf cli. still i'm having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

you are using http instead of https
Try cf api https://api.[REGION PLACEHOLDER].bluemix.net

More please be sure to set also HTTPS_PROXY env var

Comment: I have also tried using 'https' as i mentioned earlier in the post but didnt work. May be i'm having some firewall issue.

Comment: Have you also set the HTTPS_PROXY env var?

Comment: Are you able to run a telnet on the same url and port?

Comment: Hi i have done setup in another pc and its working well. I donno whats wrong with the previous one.

Comment: Probably something wrong with the previous system proxy config

Comment: Yes, that might be the reason.